# Creating Stream for StreamBuilder with Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm have created a Stream that it working inside StreamBuilder, but I have to pass some parameters to my Stream, this parameters are in a dart file which only has functions. I'm attempting to create the same code that was working, but passing the user uid.

This is what I attempted:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> main_page_stream() async*{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    Stream stream = Firestore.instance.collection('user_data').
    document(user.uid).collection('Buttons').snapshots();

    await for(var event in stream) {
      yield event.documents;
    }
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'snapshot'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: snapshot)
```

This isn't working on the home page:

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: _auth.main_page_stream(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError){
            return Container(color: Colors.red);
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData){
            print(snapshot.data);
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            return Stack(
              children: [
```

this was working:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('user_data').document('sdsajnd82173812').collection('Buttons').snapshots(),
```

Comment: The error is pointing clearly to this part of the code `yield event.snapshot.value;`.  Does event have a getter named snapshot?

Comment: The stream result from the stream is a snapshot, should I only use `yield event`?

Comment: Your return type is a Stream **<QuerySnapshot>** and that is what you should be yielding.. In this regards, try yielding just the `stream` itself

Comment: yielding only stream returns: `Class '_BroadcastStream<QuerySnapshot>' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of '_BroadcastStream<QuerySnapshot>'
Tried calling: documents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QuerySnapshot - event`  doesn't have a field `snapshot`. Instead you have to

> yield event;

And for this the function return you the `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`.

Comment: got this error: `Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List<DocumentSnapshot>')`

Comment: I think, at receiving point you have processed `QuerySnapshot`, so better yield the event.. `yield event` this returns Stream<QuerySnapshot>..

Comment: It's a type mismatch.. Could you update your function code?

Comment: Updated my answer! If you wish to yield event.documents function return should be Stream<List<DoçumentSnapshot>>.. Or if you `yield event` the function return should be Stream<QuerySnapshot>.

Comment: I will be running it now, will bring feedback

Comment: I'm having problems compiling for some reason, trying to fix it